# EAR Deployment from Eclipse Oxygen to Wildfly 12

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly

been struggling with this for a while, whenever I deploy my EAR project to wildfly by doing right click -> Run As -> Run on Server I get this error

```
20:22:35,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) 
WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear (runtime-name: 
VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear) in 0ms
20:22:35,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) 
WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" (runtime- 
name: "VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear")
20:22:35,108 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) 
MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."VetSpaEAR-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service 
jboss.deployment.unit."VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: 
Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "VetSpaEAR-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.ear"
at 
org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(
DeploymentUnitPh aseService.java:151)
at 
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(
ServiceControllerImpl.java:1714)
at 
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(
ServiceControllerImpl.java:1693)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(
ServiceControllerImpl.java:1540)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(
ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at 
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(
EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(
EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(
EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR 
["/C:/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/VetSpaEAR-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.ear"], module file com.vetspa-VetSpaEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar not found
at 
org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(
EarStructureProcessor.java:187)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(
DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
... 8 more

20:22:35,109 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 
(DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace- 
deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: 
Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"VetSpaEAR-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE 
of deployment \"VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR 
[\"/C:/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/VetSpaEAR-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.ear\"], module file com.vetspa-VetSpaEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar not 
found"}}
20:22:35,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) 
WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" with 
deployment "VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"
20:22:35,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) 
WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service 
jboss.deployment.unit."VetSpaEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: 
Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "VetSpaEAR-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.ear"
```

I know the stacktrace doesn't help too much, this is my application.xml (auto generated by maven)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" version="7">
 <display-name>VetSpaEAR</display-name>
 <module>
    <ejb>com.vetspa-VetSpaEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
 </module>
 <module>
   <web>
     <web-uri>com.vetspa-VetSpaWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
     <context-root>/VetSpaWS</context-root>
   </web>
 </module>
 <module>
   <web>
    <web-uri>com.vetspa-VetSpaRS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>/VetSpaRS</context-root>
   </web>
 </module>
 <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
```

And this is my project structure

[image: Project]

Im no expert but as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong, I read somewhere that eclipse publishes the ear as an exploded artifact rather than the compressed version, this makes sense because if I deploy it manually (via cli or gui) it works like a charm, but while developing this is just not viable. I hope you can help guys thanks for your help

- Wildfly 12.0.0
- Java 8
- Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: Have you installed [JBoss Tools](https://tools.jboss.org) in your Eclipse installation? I think you will find that helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

give this a try: right-click on the project folder -> properties -> Deployment Assembly and inspect / add the ejb jar manually

[image]